# Output behaves differently when changing lines in script

Tags: bash

In the first example, everything work properly.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Enter file name:'
read file

while read line;do
        echo $line
done < $file
```

But this doesn't:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Enter file name:'
read file

while read line;
do
        echo $line
done 
< $file
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`< $file` is a valid simple command. It redirects the input to `$file` and does nothing.

Newline in a shell script is interpreted as the end of the command (you can imagine a semicolon there). There are some exceptions (e.g. you can place a newline after a `|` and it will be ignored). Basically, if there's a newline and the command can end there, it's interpreted as the end of the command.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!